# How to automatically add package reference into project file after installing .NET package?

Tags: .net-core, f#, nuget, paket

Just getting into F#, finally figured out how to add .NET packages to projects, but the way I managed to get it to work doesn't make sense. Once the package is installed (either with `nuget` or `paket`), I have to manually add a reference to the project file (either by editing it directly or with [`dotnet add package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package)). This extra step is usually automated with other languages, so I presume that I'm doing something wrong.

These are the steps I did on a Mac M1:

1. "Install" F#

   ```
   nix-shell -p dotnet-sdk_7
   ```
2. Follow all the steps in [Get started with F# with command-line tools - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line). (No errors.)
3. Install `paket` following the [install guide](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/get-started.html#NET-Core-preferred).
4. Follow the [walkthrough](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/learn-how-to-use-paket.html#Walkthrough) on adding dependencies.

   Specifically:

   1. added `nuget FSharpPlus` to `paket.dependencies`
   2. created the `src/App/paket.references` with the the line `FSharpPlus`
   3. ran `dotnet paket install`

   Once done, simply added `open FSharpPlus` to `src/App/Program.fs`, and ran `dotnet restore` followed by `dotnet build`, which blew up with

   ```
   error FS0039: The namespace or module 'FSharpPlus' is not defined.
   ```

The fix was simple enough,

```
dotnet add src/App/App.fsproj package "FSharpPlus" --version "1.5.0"
```

but it's hard for me to believe that one has to add these references manually for each package.

---

**update**: Alright, I'm officially clueless. Just out of curiosity, I added `open Giraffe.Htmx` to `src/App/Program.fs`, then ran

```
dotnet add src/App/App.fsproj package "Giraffe.Htmx" --version "1.9.6"
dotnet build
```

and everything worked... So what is the point of using `paket` or `nuget` then?

Comment: For small projects, paket is an overkill. You need it in big projects with complex dependency graphs. For small projects, you just `dotnet add`, as you already found out, (or let your IDE do it) and the package is installed automatically.

Comment: @Martin521 Thank you! It's been quite a journey thus far..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Paket with F#, you shouldn't typically need to manually edit your project files to add references if you follow the correct steps. The process with Paket should automatically handle the dependencies. Here's a general workflow that should work:

1. Initialize Paket in your solution directory.
2. Add the dependency to the `paket.dependencies` file.
3. Add the package to the `paket.references` file in your project's directory.
4. Run `dotnet paket install` which should download the package and automatically update your project (`.fsproj`) file to include the correct references.
5. You can then use `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` to restore any additional packages and build the project.

If you're encountering issues, it's possible that there could be a problem with the Paket integration or a mismatch between the Paket version and the .NET SDK version. Checking the Paket documentation for compatibility notes or seeking help from the F# community might provide more insights. It could also be a platform-specific issue with the M1 Mac. Always ensure you are using the latest version of the tools compatible with your system.

Comment: Thank you for confirming in step 4. that the project file should indeed be automatically updated; especially because I didn't see this spelled out in the docs, but this is what makes sense. This is issue may be because of doing this on Mac and/or using Nix. Will give it a try on a Windows machine next time.

Comment: Jaden.C.Brown When you say it will update the project do you mean the reference to `Paket.Restore.targets` ? I'm trying to find a way to make it add nuget package references to fsproj. It is not supported for .net core (now .net) SDK projects I think, which is a pity because Rider has no clue about the (Nuget) dependencies of a project.